# XML RPC Type Mismatch

Tags: c#, web-services, xml-rpc

Hello I try to contact a WebService to check whether an Id is correct or not

```
public static void QualifiziererUstIdCheck()
{
   try
      {
        IQualifizierteUstIdPruefung proxy = XmlRpcProxyGen.Create<IQualifizierteUstIdPruefung>();

QualifizierteUstIdPruefAntwort ret = proxy.evatrRPC("DE123456789", "AB123456789012", "Firmenname einschl. Rechtsform", "Ort", "1234567", "Strasse und Hausnummer", "nein");

         MessageBox.Show(ret.ErrorCode);
  }
  catch (Exception)
  {             


        throw;
      }

}

            [XmlRpcMissingMapping(MappingAction.Ignore)]
            public struct QualifizierteUstIdPruefAntwort
            {
                public string Datum; 
                public string Uhrzeit; 
                public string ErrorCode; 
                public string UstId_1;
                public string UstId_2;
                public string Firmename;
                public string Ort; 
                public string PLZ; 
                public string Strasse; 
                public string Erg_Name;
                public string Erg_Ort; 
                public string Erg_PLZ; 
                public string Erg_Str; 
                public string Gueltig_ab; 
                public string Gueltig_bis; 
                public string Druck; 
            }

            [XmlRpcUrl("https://evatr.bff-online.de/")]
            public interface IQualifizierteUstIdPruefung: IXmlRpcProxy
            {
                [XmlRpcMethod ("evatrRPC")]
                QualifizierteUstIdPruefAntwort evatrRPC(string UstId_1, string UstId_2, string Firmenname, string Ort, string PLZ, string Strasse, string Druck);
            }
```

If I contact the service without using my struct, but using a string return value, i get the following answer from the Service:

```
<params> <param> <value><array><data> <value><string>UstId_1</string></value> <value><string>DE123456789</string></value> </data></array></value> </param> <param> <value><array><data> <value><string>ErrorCode</string></value> <value><string>212</string></value> </data></array></value> </param> <param> <value><array><data> <value><string>UstId_2</string></value> <value><string>AB123456789012</string></value> </data></array></value> </param> <param> <value><array><data> <value><string>Druck</string></value> <value><string>nein</string></value> </data></array></value> </param> <param> <value><array><data> <value><string>Erg_PLZ</string></value> <value><string></string></value> </data></array></value> </param> <param> <value><array><data> <value><string>Ort</string></value> <value><string>Ort</string></value> </data></array></value> </param> <param> <value><array><data> <value><string>Datum</string></value> <value><string>23.11.2015</string></value> </data></array></value> </param> <param> <value><array><data> <value><string>PLZ</string></value> <value><string>1234567</string></value> </data></array></value> </param> <param> <value><array><data> <value><string>Erg_Ort</string></value> <value><string></string></value> </data></array></value> </param> <param> <value><array><data> <value><string>Uhrzeit</string></value> <value><string>07:54:32</string></value> </data></array></value> </param> <param> <value><array><data> <value><string>Erg_Name</string></value> <value><string></string></value> </data></array></value> </param> <param> <value><array><data> <value><string>Gueltig_ab</string></value> <value><string></string></value> </data></array></value> </param> <param> <value><array><data> <value><string>Gueltig_bis</string></value> <value><string></string></value> </data></array></value> </param> <param> <value><array><data> <value><string>Strasse</string></value> <value><string>Strasse und Hausnummer</string></value> </data></array></value> </param> <param> <value><array><data> <value><string>Firmenname</string></value> <value><string>Firmenname einschl. Rechtsform</string></value> </data></array></value> </param> <param> <value><array><data> <value><string>Erg_Str</string></value> <value><string></string></value> </data></array></value> </param> </params>
```

If I use the struct i get a XmlRpc Type Mismatch Exception (response contains string value where struct expected [response])

Can you help me ?

Thanks.

Ex.StackTrace:

> bei CookComputing.XmlRpc.XmlRpcSerializer.ParseString(XmlNode node,
>   Type ValueType, ParseStack parseStack, MappingAction mappingAction)
>   bei CookComputing.XmlRpc.XmlRpcSerializer.ParseValue(XmlNode node,
>   Type ValueType, ParseStack parseStack, MappingAction mappingAction,
>   Type& ParsedType, Type& ParsedArrayType)    bei
>   CookComputing.XmlRpc.XmlRpcSerializer.ParseValue(XmlNode node, Type
>   ValueType, ParseStack parseStack, MappingAction mappingAction)    bei
>   CookComputing.XmlRpc.XmlRpcSerializer.DeserializeResponse(XmlDocument
>   xdoc, Type returnType)    bei
>   CookComputing.XmlRpc.XmlRpcSerializer.DeserializeResponse(Stream stm,
>   Type svcType)    bei
>   CookComputing.XmlRpc.XmlRpcClientProtocol.ReadResponse(XmlRpcRequest
>   req, WebResponse webResp, Stream respStm, Type returnType)    bei
>   CookComputing.XmlRpc.XmlRpcClientProtocol.Invoke(Object clientObj,
>   MethodInfo mi, Object[] parameters)    bei
>   CookComputing.XmlRpc.XmlRpcClientProtocol.Invoke(MethodInfo mi,
>   Object[] Parameters)    bei
>   XmlRpcProxy45ebfd85-1c38-4dd9-a089-68735f19a7e9.evatrRPC(String
>   UstId_1, String UstId_2, String Firmenname, String Ort, String PLZ,
>   String Strasse, String Druck)

Comment: can you post the stacktrace.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh any ideas?